# How to get user defined function comment in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to get function comment where I saved basic info that I need in my program. There are many functions that I have created name of all starts with 'stat_' and i'm retrieving their names using code below.

```
SELECT routines.routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
LEFT JOIN information_schema.parameters ON 
routines.specific_name=parameters.specific_name
WHERE routines.specific_schema='public' AND routines.routine_name LIKE 
'stat_%' ORDER BY routines.routine_name, parameters.ordinal_position;
```

Now I have all function names, and I need to get their comments.
I could not find solution, if you know please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments can be retrieved via `pg_description` by the object id.

```
SELECT p.proname,
       p.proargtypes,
       d.description
       FROM pg_proc p
            LEFT JOIN pg_description d
                      ON d.objoid = p.oid
       WHERE p.proname LIKE 'stat$_%' ESCAPE '$';
```

Comment: what is pg_proc?

Comment: @CodeMan: The catalog table for functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME AS SpName
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routines.specific_schema='public' AND routines.routine_name LIKE 'stat_%' 
ORDER BY routines.routine_name
```

then you can get source of your object by this command:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'ObjectName';
```